# Getting a TypeError when using a regex

Tags: python, regex, traceback

I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Assignment 3.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(re.match(pattern, file1))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

With this code:

```
import os
import re
import csv

pattern = "^[A-Za-z]*[,]$"
file1 = open("10000DirtyNames.csv", "r")

print(re.match(pattern, file1))

if (re.match(pattern, file1)) != None:
    print("Match")
else:
    print("Does not match")

file1.close()
```

I have run the regex in an external application so it should be parsing correctly.

Comment: You're passing the *file handle*, not the string representing its contents.

Comment: Because you are only passing the file handle and not the file content.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you really want is to look in the **content of the file**:

```
with open("10000DirtyNames.csv", "r") as file1:
    if (re.search(pattern, file1.read()):
        print("Match")
    else:
        print("Does not match")
```

Additionally, there's a difference between `re.search()` and `re.match()`, the latter works only at the start of the string (thus, anchors are implicitly set).
Lastly checking for `None` can be done via `is not None` or simply with `if x:`